# C# - Problem with verifying signature of mail message using MailBee.NET

Tags: .net, certificate

I've got a problem with verifying signature of the mail message. When I download message from the server and run Smime.Verify method it works great - I can see that message is signed by IsSigned property and get details about certificate from result of that method. After downloading message I store it in database as my new type. Object of this type contains metadata of "smime.p7s" file attached to downloaded message. I would like to implement functionality that enables user to verify message on demand. To do this I convert my message object to MailBee.Mime.MailMessage object. I add "smime.p7s" file as an attachment to that object as follows:

```
mailMessage.Attachments.Add(bytes, fileName, String.Empty, null, null, NewAttachmentOptions.None, MailTransferEncoding.Base64)
```

Then I save this message to eml file, read it back and IsSigned property is false and also list of attachements is empty. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I tried to see how it works in Thunderbird - when I export signed message to .eml file and then open it using LoadMessage method it shows that this message is signed, "smime.p7s" attachement is on the list and I can successfully get certificate details using Verify method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, problem has been solved with the help of MailBee support.

"It's about Content-Type. You can't just add "smime.p7s" attachment to make the message signed (it won't get "Content-Type: multipart/signed" header). Using Sign/SignAndEncrypt method is the only way to sign the message."